# "Error: Undefined variable" in Rails sass compilation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, sprockets

I am building a rails app and having some odd sass compilation issues.

My setup:

- Rails 6.1.3
- Ruby 3.0.0
- sass-rails 6.0.0
- sassc-rails 2.1.2

My `application.scss` basically loads a few sass files that set some variables, and at the end imports the `layout.scss` which effectively uses the imported variables.

```
// application.scss
@import "normalize";
@import "variables/colors";
@import "variables/typography";
@import "variables/sizes";
@import "layout";
```

---

```
// variables/_typography.scss
$ui-font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
$ui-font-family-title: "Lato", sans-serif;
```

---

```
// layout.scss
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  font-family: $ui-font-family-title;
}
```

---

```
// views/layouts/application.html.erb
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

---

At the beginning it worked, but then I noticed that sometimes I got an error saying

```
Error: Undefined variable: "$ui-font-family-title".
        on line 3:16 of app/assets/stylesheets/layout.scss
>>   font-family: $ui-font-family-title;
```

However, sometimes after recompiling assets (because of a change in any scss file) I noticed it could either work or fail (with that error).

I added a `@debug "Compiling filename"` to each sass file to understand the compilation order and found something very odd to me.

It always compiles every sass file two times, and the problem is that sometimes it compiles variables once and therefore it fails when compiling the `layout.scss` the second time.

This is how it looks when it works:

[image: working version]

And this is how it looks when failing:

[image]

As you can see, when it fails it compiles the `layout.scss` file twice in a row, and my guess is that since on the second iteration it doesn't import the other files, it can't find the variables as expected.

Do you have any idea on what could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I actually found the problem.

It seems that on Sprockets 4.0, the way it compiles scss files is defined here:

```
# app/assets/config/manifest.js
//= link_tree ../images
//= link_directory ../stylesheets .css
```

This basically picks any css/scss file in the `stylesheets` folder to compile.

Therefore, the solution to this issue would be whether to update the manifest to use just a `link` to the only file you want as a point of entry, or leave only the `application.scss` file in first level of the folder and move all the others to subfolders so they are not targeted by the manifest.

I ended up with this now, which works:

```
// application.scss
@import "utils/normalize";
@import "variables/colors";
@import "variables/typography";
@import "variables/sizes";
@import "pages/layout";
```

So the only scss file in `stylesheets/` (at least in the first level deep) is the `application.scss`.

You can find more information here on the [sprockets upgrading docs](https://github.com/rails/sprockets/blob/master/UPGRADING.md#manifestjs):

> You may also find that some files that were not previously compiled as top-level targets are now. For instance, if your existing app has any js files directly at ./app/assets/javascripts or css/scss files ./app/assets/stylesheets, Rails with Sprockets 4 will now compile them as top-level targets. Since they were not previously treated as such, you probably don't mean them to be; if they are .scss partials referencing variables meant to be defined in other files, it may even result in an error message that looks like Undefined variable: $some_variable.